# Why does my code exit after running twice

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc

I'm very new to python. Earlier I followed a guide to set up my new NFC scanner and it worked perfectly. The only issue is it was very bare bones as it just spat out the assigned text. I am trying to make a device that takes in 4 different key cards, and then opens. The order does not matter.

As of now I have two scripts, cardCounter and Read.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import imp
import Read
card1 = 0
card2 = 0
card3 = 0
card4 = 0
def Checker(text):
    card1 = 0
    card2 = 0
    card3 = 0
    card4 = 0
    if text == "KILL":
        GPIO.cleanup()
    print("this is working")    
    if card1 == 1 and card2 == 2:
        pass
        if card3 == 3 and card4 == 4:
            print("complete")
        else:
            sleep(1.5)
            print("sleep1")
            imp.reload(Read)
    else:
        sleep(1.5)
        print("sleep2")
        imp.reload(Read)
```

Above is my counter (and I'm still working out the variables right now) and below is the reader.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import cardCounter
import imp
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
    id, text = reader.read()
    print(id)
    print(text)
    cardCounter.Checker(text)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Currently I am able to run the counter file and scan any card. I get all my information and then it sits and waits for another input. Once I scan my second card it evaluates it and then finishes. How to I get this to stay open until all four cards are scanned? Or better yet how do I get this to continue to run back and forth until I give it a certain command? (such as having all 4 cards correctly input or a kill tag)

(If you are running this code with NFC tags on hand here is my output

```
374284575241    < first ID
1               
this is working
sleep2
857232925218    < second ID
2                                               
this is working
sleep2
/home/pi/pi-rfid/Read.py:15: RuntimeWarning: No channels have been set up yet - nothing to clean up!  Try cleaning up at the end of your program instead!
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

EDIT: I understand the variable thing, I actually set it to 0 to force it to go to the else statement. My main problem is that after it calls the reader a second time, then it just exits the code. Why is this?

Comment: `if card1 == 1 and card2 == 2:` will never succeed. You just set those two variables to `0` a couple of lines before.

Comment: Nothing ever changes the `card1` through `card4` variables. How do you expect those `if` statements to ever succeed?

Comment: The `cardX` variables inside the `Checker` function are not the same as the global variables with the same names, since you have no `global` statements for them.

Comment: I understand the variable thing, I actually set it to 0 to force it to go to the else statement. My main problem is that after it calls the reader a second time, then it just exits the code. Why is this?

Comment: There's no loop, why should it keep going?

Comment: I was having trouble with a loop function so I set each program to call the other, cardChecker calls Read, and read calls cardChecker. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are intending to use the `imp.reload` function as a way to call-back to the parent (calling) function. This is not the intention of the `import` function, and also it's not a "Pythonic" way to write your code. (Also, as a rule, it's a good idea to avoid `imp.reload` function in general, but that's another story.)

To my eyes, the way to accomplish this in a manner that is simple and easy to understand is to just use a return value from your `Checker` function and a simple `while` loop in your main code. For example, in `Checker` you could just `return True` for success (this would replace your line `print ("complete")`) and `return False` for failure / try again (this would replace your lines `imp.reload(Read)`). *You would not import or reload `Read` at all in this file.* Then your "Read" file would be as follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import cardCounter
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
    gotAllCards = False
    while not gotAllCards:
        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        print(text)
        gotAllCards = cardCounter.Checker(text)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

This makes the intention of the code clearer, I'd say.